# Передача картинки рабочего стола java windows в android с помощью socket

Tags: java, android, сокет, bitmap, bufferedimage

Всем доброго времени суток, пишу программу, типа radmin для сдачи в универе. Не могу организовать передачу картинки изображения рабочего стола.
Пробовал c помощью свиньи(свинга) или BufferedImage
server PC

```
            while(true) {
        try {
            System.gc();
            img = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
            icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            os.writeObject(icon);
            os.flush();
            icon = null;
            System.gc();
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(sleepInterval);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            closeAll();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Client Android

```
                    InetAddress  serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.131");
                Socket sc = new Socket(serverAddr,4020);
                sc.getOutputStream();
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ois);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Он выдает ошибку  cast the imageIcon or the BufferedImage to Bitmap
Может кто подскажет, как эту ошибку обойти или вообще возможно этим путем решить задачу или выбрать другой путь